# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Update query with variable column

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I am using the first time the command EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and I like to ask if you can help me.

I have a variable column, because of that I search on the internet and found the EXECUTION IMMEDIATE command but it gives me the following Error:

> ORA-00904: "ACTUATION": invalid identifier
>   ORA-06512: at line 9

I am really confused, because ACTUATION is the "old_val" column and not the "column_name" column maybe you can help me. Here is the code:

```
declare
cursor such is 
select column_name, old_val, CTN.ID from abc.firsttable
ctn, def.secondtable#CC ctncc
where CTN.bup#rev = CTNCC.bup#rev
and ID in (127605689)
and CTN.bup#changefrom > to_date ('08/06/2017', 'dd/MM/YYYY');
begin
for srec in such loop 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'update firsttable ctn2
set ctn.' || srec.column_name || ' = '|| srec.old_val ||' 
where CTN2.ID = '|| srec.id;
end loop; 
end;
```

Comment: Construct the SQL query and print it out.  95% of the time, the error is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think so, you must add more `'` between params of string:

show this, in your code i added 3 `'` between `|| srec.old_val ||`

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'update firsttable ctn2
set ctn.' || srec.column_name || ' = '''|| srec.old_val ||'''
where CTN2.ID = '|| srec.id;
end loop; 
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it is so simple you can't see the problem.

Comment: Note, this will fail for values like `don't quote it like this`

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   'update firsttable ctn2
    set ctn.' || srec.column_name || ' = :OldVal 
    where CTN2.ID = :id' 
using srec.old_val, srec.id;
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, in terms of performance and scalability.